# Validation message not displayed for max-length

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a dynamic form where I'm using material design to display textbox, checkbox etc. I have added some validations dynamically and it is working fine but it is not displaying the message for max-length and min-length.

The dynamic validation doesn't allow user to enter more characters but the message is also not there.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width: 30%;">
              <input matInput [placeholder]="input.title" [formControlName]="input.name"
                [(ngModel)]="inputData[input.name]" [required]="input.validator.required"
                [minlength]="input.validator.minlength" [maxlength]="input.validator.maxlength">

              <div class="error"
                *ngIf="formCheck.get(formName).get(input.name).invalid &&
                                    (formCheck.get(formName).get(input.name).dirty ||
                                    formCheck.get(formName).get(input.name).touched)">
                <div *ngIf="formCheck.get(formName).get(input.name).hasError('required')">Input required</div>
                <div *ngIf="formCheck.get(formName).get(input.name).errors?.minlength">Minimum length is
                  {{input.validator.minlength}}</div>
                <div *ngIf="formCheck.get(formName).get(input.name).errors?.maxlength">Maximum length is
                  {{input.validator.maxlength}}</div>
              </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

dynamic-form.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.css'],
})
export class DynamicFormComponent {
  @Input() fields: formControls[] = [];
  @Input() formCheck: FormGroup;
  @Input() formName: string;
  @Input() inputData: any;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  get value() {
    return this.formCheck.value;
  }

  onValueChange(event) {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

How can I display validation messages below or next to input fields?

I have added the component.ts file. I use this component as child component and send the following:
1. fields - array consisting of controls detail
2. Model object which will store the data entered in the form.
3. formName
4. formgroup

Comment: where are you defining the variable `input`? Are you sure it's of type `Control`?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine for me except displaying the validation message for max-length. I'm using this and here fields is an array of controls with all control properties: <ng-template ngFor let-input [ngForOf]="fields">
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="input.controlType">

Comment: could u clear for us what the model for formName looks like?

Comment: Also pls show ur component.ts file

Comment: This is very bad practice of using Reactive Forms. Please do not use ngModel with Reactive Form..

Comment: I read about this but I'm not sure what is the other best way of saving data in the object. Also, the warning message says that this will be deprecated in Angular 7 but I can still use this. Can you please suggest the best way without using ngModel?

Comment: Check the example for form validation using `Validators` of Angular. https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form